# debezium - change of topic name gives the error cross-database references

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I am using this [debezium-examples](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-smt)

**source.json**

```
{
"name": "inventory-connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
    "database.whitelist": "inventory",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory",
    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
}
}
```

**jdbc-sink.json**

```
{
"name": "jdbc-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "customers",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/inventory?user=postgresuser&password=postgrespw",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "pk.mode": "record_value"
}
}
```

I have run this example its working fine.But when I have made some changes as discuss in the following scenario. it giving me 'cross-database references' error.

***Scenario***

I have remove these properties from source

```
    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
```

now it creating topic in kafka as follow

```
dbServer1.inventory.products

dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand

dbserver1.inventory.customers

dbserver1.inventory.orders
```

When I specified topic= `dbserver1.inventory.customers` in jdbc-sink, it giving me the following **exception**

```
 ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: 
"dbserver1.inventory.customers" at character 14
postgres_1   | STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE "dbserver1"."inventory"."customers" (
postgres_1   |  "last_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
postgres_1   |  "id" INT NOT NULL,
postgres_1   |  "first_name" TEXT NOT NULL,
postgres_1   |  "email" TEXT NOT NULL,
postgres_1   |  PRIMARY KEY("id"))
connect_1    | 2019-01-29 09:39:18,931 WARN   ||  Create failed, will attempt amend if table already exists   [io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure]
connect_1    | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "dbserver1.inventory.customers"
connect_1    |   Position: 14
```

Note: Its not duplicate as other question is also posted by me, which is covering different scenario

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debezium confluent - change of transforms.route.replacement gives the SinkRecordField error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420019/debezium-confluent-change-of-transforms-route-replacement-gives-the-sinkrecord)

Comment: Its not duplicate as other question is also posted by me, which is covering different scenario

Comment: I don't know Postgres, but is the `(name).(name).(name)` format supported? One is the database, another the table... what is the third?

Answer (score 1):

change inventory -> dbserver1

`(databasename).(schemaname).(tablename)`

```
{
"name": "jdbc-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "customers",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/dbserver1?user=postgresuser&password=postgrespw",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "pk.mode": "record_value"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `table.name.format` sink property solved this for me. It allows you to override what the destination table name will be. See https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_config_options.html